# R: how to pass a variable into a function to subset data.frame

Tags: r

```
 dat = data.frame(height = c(20, 20, 40, 50, 60, 10), weight = c(100, 200, 300, 200, 140, 240),
             age = c(19, 20, 20, 19, 10, 11))
 f = function(x){
   subset.19 = dat$x[dat$age == 20]
   subset.20 = dat$x[dat$age == 19]
   t.test(subset.19, subset.20)  
 }
 f("weight")
```

I get an error:

Error in var(x) : 'x' is NULL
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
2: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

I think this is because `dat$x` is always NULL because there is no column named `x` in the data.frame. I think I am not passing the variable name into the function. `dat$x` is always subsetting the column named `x` from `dat`, not the column name that I passed in (i.e. weight). So my question is how can I pass in the column name that I want so this function runs?

Comment: The main point is that you have to use `[` instead of `$` when passing the column name in a variable. You could read about that by typing `help("[")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @agstudy and @docendodiscimus mentioned in the comments, it is better to use `[`, `[[` instead of `$` when passing column name in functions.

```
 f <- function(x){
     subset.19 = dat[,x][dat$age == 20]
     subset.20 = dat[,x][dat$age == 19]
   t.test(subset.19, subset.20)  
 }
f("weight")
```